# Change button's background colour

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, subclass

I am working on a project in which I create a subclass for UIButton for setting the gradient background colour.Its working fine but now there are two tabs in a ViewController there is two buttons suppose A and B. I want to change colour of button A when I clicked on Button B same like tabs functionality:

Sub class of UIButton:

```
// .h_file
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface grediantButton : UIButton

@property(nonatomic)IBInspectable UIColor*topColor;
@property(nonatomic)IBInspectable UIColor*bottomColor;

@property(nonatomic)IBInspectable CGFloat cornerRadius;

- (void)customInit;
@end

// .m file
#import "grediantButton.h"
#import "UIColor+myColor.h"
@implementation grediantButton

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        self.topColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.bottomColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.cornerRadius = 1;
        [self customInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self customInit];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [self customInit];
}

- (void)setNeedsLayout {
    [super setNeedsLayout];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}


- (void)prepareForInterfaceBuilder {

    [self customInit];
}

- (void)customInit {

    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.cornerRadius;

    CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer =  [[CAGradientLayer alloc] init];
    gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds;


    gradientLayer.cornerRadius = self.cornerRadius;

    gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[self.topColor CGColor], (id)[self.bottomColor CGColor],nil];

    [self.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [self.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0];

}
```

My VC Code:

```
#pragma mark:AddnewTownshipVC
- (IBAction)addnewTownShip:(id)sender {

    [self.addnewTwnBtn setTopColor:[UIColor getTabTopColor]];
    [self.addnewTwnBtn setBottomColor:[UIColor getTabBotColor]];


    [self.viewalltownBtn setTopColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.viewalltownBtn setBottomColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

}

#pragma mark:viewalltownshipVC
- (IBAction)viewAllTownship:(id)sender {

    [self.addnewTwnBtn setTopColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.addnewTwnBtn setBottomColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    [self.viewalltownBtn setTopColor:[UIColor getTabTopColor]];
    [self.viewalltownBtn setBottomColor:[UIColor getTabBotColor]];

  }
```

Tabs is like:
[image: I want to change these tab color alternate by taping on buttons]

what happen when I click on black one tab

[image]

Comment: What is the issue then ?

Comment: I'm not able to change the color showing in code "[self.addnewTwnBtn setTopColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.addnewTwnBtn setBottomColor:[UIColor blackColor]];"

Comment: It is obvious   by just passing value   to property `bottomColor` how it will set the color ? You didn't write any code for that

Comment: Do one thing for button selected state set that golden colour and for normal state set black color. now on tap of button just change `sender.selected = !sender.selected`

Comment: This method - (void)customInit is calling every time when I clicked. and I set all thinks in it. You can check above code

Comment: Agree with @PrashantTukadiya, also you may just add a setter to set buttons background color to `bottomColor` in `initWithFrame`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for response.
I solved my issue by change some code in my - (void)customInit method

```
- (void)customInit {


    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.cornerRadius;

    CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer =  [[CAGradientLayer alloc] init];
    gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds;


    gradientLayer.cornerRadius = self.cornerRadius;

    gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[self.topColor CGColor], (id)[self.bottomColor CGColor],nil];

    [self.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

    if([[self.layer sublayers] objectAtIndex:0]){
        [self.layer replaceSublayer:[[self.layer sublayers] objectAtIndex:0] with:gradientLayer];
    }else{
            [self.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0];
    }

}
```

and call this method in

```
#pragma mark:AddnewTownshipVC
- (IBAction)addnewTownShip:(grediantButton*)sender {

    [sender setTopColor:[UIColor getTabTopColor]];
    [sender setBottomColor:[UIColor getTabBotColor]];

    [sender customInit];


    [self.viewalltownBtn setTopColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.viewalltownBtn setBottomColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    [self.viewalltownBtn customInit];

//    sender.isSelected = true;
//    self.viewalltownBtn.isSelected = false;

}

#pragma mark:viewalltownshipVC
- (IBAction)viewAllTownship:(grediantButton*)sender {

    [self.addnewTwnBtn setTopColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.addnewTwnBtn setBottomColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    [self.addnewTwnBtn customInit];

    [sender setTopColor:[UIColor getTabTopColor]];
    [sender setBottomColor:[UIColor getTabBotColor]];
    [sender customInit];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set state for UIButton multiple states.
For example, set different background images for different states.

```
[button setBackgroundImage:naomalImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setBackgroundImage:selectedImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

And then, just control states.

```
- (IBAction)addnewTownShip:(id)sender {
    button.selected = YES;
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

simply go to the attribute inspector in storyboard see in bottom in it there has background colour you can change with it.

see here :-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6ecY.png